# Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> После участия в мистическом варьете(,) моя популярность взорвалась.

Нужна ли запятая перед словом "моя"? Подскажите и поясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая не нужна:

*После участия в мистическом варьете / **моя популярность взорвалась.***

1. Это **простое** предложение, которое делится на две части по принципу **тема-рема** (предмет и сообщение о предмете). Между частями предложения делается короткая **произносительная пауза**, которая **не обозначается** запятой. Интонация ровная, спокойная, без логического подчеркивания.
2. Посмотрим на **грамматику** предложения. В первой части обстоятельственный **оборот** со значением времени (когда?), а во второй части основное сообщение. Обычно такие предложные обороты **не обособляются**: **у [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114)** это тема: § 20. Обособленные обстоятельства. Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными.
3. Могут обособляться распространенные обороты на основе **производных** предлогов, да и то не всегда. Это называется актуализацией оборота, то есть его **особое подчеркивание**, выделение голосом. Ничего этого в данном случае нет. Обозначение запятой произносительной паузы — это проблема **"лишних запятых"**.

**Замечание по стилистике**

Я бы написала так: *После участия в мистическом варьете моя популярность **"взорвалась".***

Почему? Здесь **не совсем обычное** сочетание слов. Глагол ***взорваться***  имеет нужное по словарю **значение,** но необходимо существительное в качестве распространителя: **ВЗОРВАТЬСЯ**, -св. 2. чем. (в сочет. с отвлеч. сущ.). Внезапно и бурно начать действие, указанное существительным. Зал взорвался **хохотом**. Публика взорвалась **аплодисментами**.

Смотрим **в Карту слов**: сочетаемость для слов [популярность](https://kartaslov.ru/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) и  [взорваться](https://kartaslov.ru/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F). Обычное сочетание такое: ***популярность выросла***.